# Xamarin orientation info.plist

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am having a problem in ISO setting the device orientation. For iPhone I would like to lock it to only Portrait mode but for iPad I would like the user to be able to use Portrait, Landscape left and right. The setting will not save for each device.

> Do I need to do this a different way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your info.plist with a text editor. There should be two orientation sections where you can define orientations per idiom as follows

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

If this isn't working properly, you can also address this in code. In AppDelegate.cs try overriding GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations.

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations
(
  UIApplication application, 
  [Transient] UIWindow forWindow
)
{
  // You will need to figure out how to determine what kind of device you're on. I suggest Xamarin.Essentials, they probably have a service for that.
  if (iPhone)
  {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
  }

  if (iPad)
  {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
  }

  return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
}
```

Comment: For the iPhone when I go left it good staying in portrait but when right it goes to Landscape

Comment: @Jefferson Added a way to address this programatically to this answer.